# I can't upload text to Mysql with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a comment board. Here is my table create by PHPMyAdmin
[image]

I set the guestID as primary key and auto-increment, but every time I trying to input a new guest name by php, it only could create a new column with a new ID but without the name.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("guest");
mysql_query("set names utf8");

$guestName=$_POST['guestName'];


mysql_query("insert into guest value(`guestID`, `guestName`)");


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="top">
<h3>New comment</h3>
</div>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="guestName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name：</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="guestName" name="guestName" id="guestName" />
        </div>


    <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="send" class="btn"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not substituting the value of the variable into the query. And the keyword before the list of values is `values`, not `value`.

```
$guestName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['guestName']);

mysql_query("insert into guest (guestName) values ('$guestName')");
```

And notice that you must use single quotes around the string, not backticks. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

You should also upgrade to `mysqli` or `PDO` and use prepared statements instead of the obsolete `mysql` extension. But if you use `mysql`, you should escape user input to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

As you have set Primary key and Autoincrement for guestID field then don't use it in insert query because it will get increment values automatically when you will insert a new row. And the other mistake you made is, You have not passed column names.

```
$guestName=$_POST['guestName'];


mysql_query("insert into guest (guestName) value(".$guestName.") ");
```

In above mentioned query, notice that there are two brackets, first is for column names, and in the same sequence you need to write values' bracket.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Backticks are wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: @seamaszhou, happy to help. You may accept the answer.

Comment: yes @Barmar, I forgot to remove them. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Now it's wrong because you don't have any quotes around the string.